# How do I connect my TV (Samsung 32D5000) with ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu

Recently I have bough a TV set, a smart TV from Samsung: D5000, and I am trying to watch movies from my computer on this TV. I have connected my TV through lan to my modem Huawei HG655b, the same that my computer is connected to. I have given my TV an ip adress and everything and the message was that it connects to the internet.

I would like to know how to create a dlna server from ubuntu system (my computer)so that I can see my movies ont the television.

So far I have tried installing mediatomb, and configuring it...but after I have done this the server did not responde, I typed in mediatomb on the terminal and it opened the browser saying server could not connect, what would be the next step.... I can't figure it out....(I'm new to ubuntu, and to Linux in general).

If you could explain it to me step by step I would be greatfull.

Comment: Huawei HG655b is not a modem, it's a router...

Comment: install samba and share out the folders, the tv will see the shares as an input. This works with my D6000.